# Java, algoritmo hay dinero en una hucha

Tags: java

dado este enunciado

Como podría hacerlo? no termino de sacarlo

Uso dos Array, uno para el valor y otro para la cantidad de ese valor, empiezo a restar desde el mas alto, para nunca quedarme sin  cambio

- hayDinero: Recibirá una cantidad de dinero y devolverá verdadero si hay monedas suficientes y falso en caso contrario.
- sacarDinero: recibirá un numero correspondiente a una cantidad de dinero. Si la cantidad  solicitada se puede obtener cn las monedas de la hucha, se mostrará un mensaje con la cantidad de monedas proporcionada de cada tipo y se descontará de la hucha.

  ```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] valor = {1, 2, 5};
  int[] cantidad = {1, 2, 4};
  int contador = valor.length - 1;
  int total = 24;
  //total es la suma de todo el array
  int dinero = 23;
  boolean hayDinero = false;
  if (total >= dinero) {
      do {
          if (cantidad[contador] != 0 & dinero >= valor[contador]) {

              dinero = dinero - valor[contador];

              cantidad[contador]--;
          }else{
              contador--; 
          }

      } while (dinero >= 0 & contador >= 0);
  }
  if(dinero==0){
      hayDinero=true;
  }
  System.out.println(dinero + " " + total);
  System.out.println(hayDinero);
  ```

  }

El problema, es como hago para el segundo modulo, es decir la cantidad de monedas que tengo que sacar si  haydinero, que tendría  copiar el algoritmo de este para usarlo con unos añadidos en este modulo, para saber la cantidad de monedas de cada tipo que cojo ?

No se me ocurre otra forma para no copiar este modulo en el segundo con unos añadidos de salida por consola + lo que pide

Comment: Y cual es el problema? podrias explicar el problema de tu codigo?

Comment: Hola, perdona por mi falta de explicación, el problema es que no se hacer el segundo modelo  la parte de la cantidad de monedas que necesito, el modulo escrito, sería el de hayDinero

Comment: Yo sigo sin entender, que hace ese codigo, y cual es el problema particular.

Comment: Tiene que ser el mínimo numero de monedas posibles o da igual cuales cojas?

Comment: tiene que ser el minimo, para no quedarte sin cambio es decir, si quieres 5 € y tienes una moneda de 5€ y 5 monedas de 1€ tienes que coger la de 5€, siempre empezando por arriba

Comment: @gbianchi el codigo hace que si hay dinero suficiente para la cantidad pedida, y siempre dando primero las monedas o billetes mayores, para no quedarse sin cambio y en caso de que variable dinero== 0 entonces es que se ha cogido  el dinero necesario para cubrir la cantidad deseada con el dinero que habia en la hucha

Comment: y entonces cual es el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente mételo en un array y si es posible alcanzar esa cantidad muestras este array diciendo cuáles son las que coges:

```
public static void main(String Args[])
{
    int[] valor = {1, 2, 5};
    int[] cantidad = {1, 2, 4};
    int contador = valor.length - 1;
    int total = 24;
    //total es la suma de todo el array
    int dinero = 23;
    boolean hayDinero = false;

    int[] cuales = new int[valor.length];
    if (total >= dinero) {
        do {
            if (cantidad[contador] != 0 & dinero >= valor[contador]) {

                dinero = dinero - valor[contador];

                cuales[contador]++;

                cantidad[contador]--;
            }else{
                contador--; 
            }

        } while (dinero >= 0 & contador >= 0);
    }
    if(dinero==0){
        hayDinero=true;
    }

    System.out.println(dinero + " " + total);
    System.out.println(hayDinero);

    if(hayDinero){
        System.out.println("Cuantas de cada tipo:");
        for(int j = 0; j < cuales.length; j++){
            System.out.println(cuales[j] + " monedas de valor " + valor[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es esto lo que me faltaba, ahora tengo una duda con respecto a las instrucciones, esto son como dos modulos, hayDinero y sacarDinero, pero con respecto a los dos solo se varia algo, " la cantidad de monedas a devolver " es normal esto?