# Java, problema con clase y aplicación dinero

Tags: java

tengo el siguiente codigo y no sé donde falla

los métodos son:

- valorTotal: devolverá el valor total en euros del contenido de la hucha.
- hayDinero: recibirá una cantidad de dinero y devolverá dverdadero si hay monedas suficiente y falso en caso contrario.
- sacarDinero: recibirá un numero correspondiente a una cantidad de dinero. SI la hucha esta cerrada debe escribir un mensajke en pantalla y no hacer nada. Si la cantidad solicitada se puede obtener  con las monedas de la hucha se monstrará un mensaje con la cantidad de moneda proporcionada de cada tipo y se descontrara de la hucha en cualquier otro caso de monstrara un mensaje que indique lo ocurrido:

clase

public class Dinero {

```
//Atributos:
```

final  int[] valor={1,2,5};
    int[] cantidad;
    int [] cuales;
    boolean abierta;

```
//Contructores:
public Dinero(boolean modo) {
    this.abierta = modo;
}
//Métodos:

public void abrirLaHucha() {
    this.abierta = true;
}//Fin Procedimiento

public void ingresar(int d1, int d2, int d5) {
    cantidad= new int[valor.length];
    cuales = new int[valor.length];
    cantidad[0] = cantidad[0] + d1;
    cantidad[1] = cantidad[1] + d2;
    cantidad[2] = cantidad[2] + d5;
}//Fin Procedimiento

public int valorTotal() {
    //Entorno:
    int valorTotal;
    //Algoritmo:
    valorTotal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < valor.length; i++) {
        valorTotal = valorTotal + valor[i] * cantidad[i];
    }//Fin Para
    return valorTotal;
}//Fin Función

public boolean hayDinero(int dinero) {
    //Entorno:
    int totalDinero;
    int contador;
    boolean hayDinero;
    int[] copiaCantidad;
    //Algoritmo:
    copiaCantidad=new int [cantidad.length];
  copiaCantidad[0]=cantidad[0];
   copiaCantidad[1]=cantidad[1];
    copiaCantidad[2]=cantidad[2];
    contador = valor.length - 1;
    hayDinero = false;
    totalDinero = valorTotal();
    if (totalDinero >= dinero) {
        do {

            if (copiaCantidad[contador] != 0 & dinero >= valor[contador]) {

                dinero = dinero - valor[contador];
                cuales[contador]++;    
                copiaCantidad[contador]--;
            } else {
                contador--;
            }

        } while (dinero >= 0 & contador >= 0);
    }
    if (dinero == 0) {
        hayDinero = true;
    }

    return hayDinero;
}//Fin Función

public void sacarDinero(int dinero) {
    //Algoritmo:
    if (!abierta) {
        System.out.println("La Hucha esta cerrada");
    } else {
        if (hayDinero(dinero)) {
            System.out.println("Cuantas de cada tipo:");
            for (int j = 0; j < cuales.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(cuales[j] + " monedas de valor " + valor[j]);
                cantidad[j]--;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se puede sacar la cantidad solicitada");
        }
    }//Fin Si

}//Fin Procedimiento
```

}

Aplicacion

```
public class DineroA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Entorno:
            Dinero x;
        //Algoritmo:
        x = new Dinero(true);
        x.ingresar(1, 2, 4);
        System.out.println(x.valorTotal());

         System.out.println(x.valorTotal());
        x.sacarDinero(20);
         System.out.println(x.valorTotal());
    }

}
```

Salida

```
    25
25
Cuantas de cada tipo:
0 monedas de valor 1
0 monedas de valor 2
4 monedas de valor 5
17
```

Salida Esperada

```
  25
    25
    Cuantas de cada tipo:
    0 monedas de valor 1
    0 monedas de valor 2
    4 monedas de valor 5
    5
```

la funcion que parece que da problemas es sacarDinero()

Comment: y cual deberia ser la salida correcta en este caso? supongo que 5 monedas de 5?

Comment: debería de ser  el valor total despues 5; la última linea

Comment: si x.sacarDinero(20); (como escribiste) entonces 4 esta correcto. no se de donse salen esos 25

Comment: esos 25 son de cuando se han ingresado 1 moneda de 1€, 2 monedas de 2€, y 4 monedas de 5€. Pero lo que está mal es la ultima linea de salida, debería de salir 5

Comment: podes ser mucho mas claro? pone el resultado que obtenes, y cual es el resultado esperado, y la funcion que te genera problemas. asi es muy dificil ayudarte.. y proba tambien hacer un debug de tu programa, seguir linea por linea tu codigo. seguramente asi encontraras muchos de los problemas que nombras.

Comment: Perdona, la salida esperada es :    25
25
Cuantas de cada tipo:
0 monedas de valor 1
0 monedas de valor 2
4 monedas de valor 5
5 La función que parece que da problemas es sacarDinero;

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Java, algoritmo hay dinero en una hucha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143789/java-algoritmo-hay-dinero-en-una-hucha)